# How to skip rows that have no data in specific column

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

Ex:

```
"ActivityId":7177,"ReferenceId":0,"Key":0,"FirstName":"Kerthana","LastName":"thanneru","CId":"00050068953"
"ActivityId":6216,"ReferenceId":42234,"Key":0,"FirstName":"Krishna","LastName":"thanneru","CId":null,"Specialty":null,"InviteeType":
```

I want to use `ActivityId":6216` which I correlated. But I want use it only if CId has data. If CId is null, I need to skip it.

This is ForEach Controller configuration:

[image]

Could someone please help me to figure out how to skip rows which have null in CId column?

Comment: Where the data is coming from? Also please read [ForEach manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), your configuration makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

If your [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) won't allow null values, it will ignore activity Ids with null CId.

This work for me with your given text for ignoring null in CId column:

```
ActivityId":(\d+)([^\t\n]+)CId":"
```

Comment: Is there any option or way to ActivityId pic values always ("ActivityId":7177,"ReferenceId":0,) "ReferenceId"==0, or else skip the loop in this combination

Comment: @KrishnaMurthy yes, add it to regex

Comment: `ActivityId":(\d+),"ReferenceId":0,([^\t\n]+)CId":"`

Comment: Not Work. I want Pic ActivityId when ReferenceId=0.EX: ("ActivityId":6449,"ReferenceId":6583577,) this combination ReferenceId have value, so i need to skip this value and ("ActivityId":6449,"ReferenceId":0,) now ReferenceId=0 now i need to pick  ActivityId. Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Please give me the regex for this two values only. "ActivityId":7177,"ReferenceId":0, no CId value

Comment: @KrishnaMurthy `ActivityId":(\d+),"ReferenceId":0,([^\t\n]+)CId":"`

Comment: No, it is not working. i have written some java script for resolving

Answer (score 0):

For every line you can do this:

```
    if line =~ /.*?CId["]:"?[0-9]+"?.*/; puts line end
```

Comment: Is there any option or way ActivityId to pic values always ("ActivityId":7177,"ReferenceId":0,) "ReferenceId"==0, or else skip the loop in this combination

Comment: HI, you can use this:

/.*?ActivityId"?:7177.*?ReferenceId"?:0.*?CId["]:"?[0-9]+"?.*/

Answer (score 0):

Use the IF controller and in that put the condition as ${__jexl3("${CId}"!= null,)}
And then if your CId is not null then that row should be picked up.!!
I am considering that your data is coming from an external source like csv file or so..!!